# How to close reading inputStream in java

Tags: java, android, mobile, inputstream

The input stream is not closing even though i closed it.
I don't know how to close the input stream, because I'm still new to this
The below code is for Sending data

```
while (socket!=null)
            {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                try {


                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        out.append(line);
                    }
                    handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ_DONE,out.toString()).sendToTarget(); 
                    reader.read();
                    reader.close();
       }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    try {
                        if (reader != null){
                            reader.close();
                        }
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

this is for writeTheData

```
public void write(byte[] bytes)
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (outputStream!=null){
                        try {
                            outputStream.write(bytes);

                            outputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "null data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: how do you check that inputStream is not closing?

Comment: when i debug, in  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        out.append(line);
                    }

Comment: ok, then how are you closing it then? I only see that you are closing it **after** hat code.

Comment: Thatsit,,i think close the inputstream just like that,,any code to close the inpus stream?

Comment: just use `.close()` on the stream you want to close. But that is not what you need for sure.

Comment: Thats nothing happen,,same too,,

Comment: As I said - because that is not what you need. In your code you are not trying to close the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the buffered Reader like this.Think closing the buffered Reader will solve your problem.

reader.close();

Comment: Where to place it?

Answer (score 0):

reader != null always return true because BufferedReader was initialized. There is no method or workaround to check whether the reader is closed or not.